# PowerShell for Modifying AD user display name from a specific OU

Tags: powershell

I need to update the displayname of the AD user. It is already updated to something else . But i want in this format

First Name = Vineet

Last Name = Chaturvedi

Displayname = Vineet.chatturvedi-TA

Please help me

```
$displayname = "$firstname.$lastname";
```

Comment: `Set-ADUser -DisplayName $displayname`

Comment: Where do you get the extra `t` in `chatturvedi` in the display name? And where does the `-TA` suffix come from? Should that be the same for all users?